# How would I only invert every second element in a 2D boolean array?

Tags: java

Below is my code so far. I would like to make every second value in the array false, and the left over values true. Then I would like to invert the array (true = false, and false = true). I have the invert part down, but not the make every second value false to start down.

```
public class Stack {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ROW = 10, COL = 10;
    boolean[][] ATwoDBoolArray = new boolean[ROW][COL];

    PutValuesInArray(ATwoDBoolArray);
    printArray(ATwoDBoolArray);
    invertArray(ATwoDBoolArray);
    printArray(ATwoDBoolArray);

}

private static boolean[][] PutValuesInArray(boolean array[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = false;

        }

    }

    return array;
}

private static void printArray(boolean[][] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(array[i][j]);

        }

    }

}

private static boolean[][] invertArray(boolean array[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if(array[i][j]){
                array[i][j] = false;

            }else{
                array[i][j] = true;

            }

        }

    }


    return array;
}

}
```

Comment: have a loop that increments in steps of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method of doing it would be to change `PutValuesInArray(boolean array[][])` to the below code:

```
private static boolean[][] PutValuesInArray(boolean array[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j+=2) {
            array[i][j] = true;

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < array[i].length; j+=2) {
            array[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2)
    array[i] = false;
```

Increment by `2` instead of `1`.

Start the loop at `int i = 1` to set all odd elements false.

---

If your arrays are less than 32 elements long, you could use a single `int` to store 32 boolean values in its bits. And *then* you could make every add element false like this:

```
int array;

array &= 0x55555555; // set odd bits false
array &= 0xAAAAAAAA; // set even bits false
```

Comment: I gave you an up vote for the interesting information; however, I have to give the other answer the check mark, because it is slightly more applicable.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a checkerboard pattern you’re after—I suggest the following:

```
boolean[][] array = new boolean[5][5];

for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x ++)
    for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y ++)
        if((x + y) % 2 == 0)
            array[x][y] = true;
```

This will create an array with its elements set to `true` and `false` in a checkerboard pattern kind of fashion.

This `5 x 5` array—after generated—will look like this:

```
boolean[][] array = {
    {true, false, true, false, true}, 
    {false, true, false, true, false}, 
    {true, false, true, false, true}, 
    {false, true, false, true, false}, 
    {true, false, true, false, true}
}
```